# Equivariant isometric embedding of manifolds in a Hilbert space under a noncompact group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, embeddings

Given a Riemannian manifold $M$ and a group of isometries $G$ of $M$, I am interested in when there exists a isometric embedding $\iota : M \to H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and a representation $\rho : G \to \mathcal{B} (H; H)$ such that for each $g \in G$ and $x \in M$,
$$
  \iota (g (x)) = \rho (g) \iota (x).
$$

When $M$ is a compact manifold and $G$ is a compact Lie group compact, then this is possible with a finite dimensional space $H \simeq \mathbb{R}^\nu$ (whose dimension depends on the dimension of $M$ and on the structure of $G$); when $M$ is not compact anymore $H$ can be taken to a separable Hilbert space (Moore, Schlafly, *On equivariant isometric embeddings*, Math. Z., 1980).

I would like to know what happens when the group $G$ is not compact anymore: when is it still possible to obtain an equivariant embedding in a (sufficiently large) Hilbert space?

Comment: Since you said "a (sufficiently large) Hilbert space" I guess you know that for $M$ a symmetric space of non compact type and $G$ the connected component of the group of isometries such equivariant embedding does not exist for a finite dimensional one due to a Theorem of Vargas: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-01/S0002-9939-1981-0589158-X/S0002-9939-1981-0589158-X.pdf

Comment: This solves positively the homogeneous case: http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/embed.pdf

Comment: @Holonomia could you fix the broken link?

Comment: @Math_Newbie :  https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/embed.pdf

In future if the link does not work : the file "embed.pdf" contains a proof by Michael E. Taylor of the claim that homogeneous Riemannian manifolds can be equivariantly isometrically embedded into a Hilbert space.